# Commutative Diagram on Forms.

Tags: differential-geometry

How can I Prove that this diagram commute for all q:

$$\begin{array}
ΩΩ^q(U) & \stackrel{f^*}{\longleftarrow} & Ω^q(V) \\
\uparrow{d} & & \uparrow{d} \\
Ω^{q+1}(U) & \stackrel{f^*}{\longleftarrow} & Ω^{q+1}(V)   
\end{array}
$$

where $U$  is an open in $\mathbb {R} ^m$ and $V$  is an open in $\mathbb {R} ^n$ and $f^*(w) = f^*(\sum_I g_I dx_I) = \sum_I (g_I \circ f dx_I)$.

Please help……

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ is a vector field on $U$ and $u\in\Omega^0(V)$ is a smooth function on $V$, then
$$f^*(du)(X)=du(f_*X)=f_*X(u)=X(f^*u)=df^*u(X)$$
Suppose now $v\in\Omega^0(V)$,
$$f^*d(udv)=f^*(du\wedge dv)=f^*du\wedge f^*dv=df^*u\wedge df^*v=df^*(udv)$$
Next we assume community holds for any $\omega\in\Omega^r(V)$ where $r<q$, $\eta\in\Omega^1(V)$ then
$$\begin{align}
df^*(\eta\wedge\omega)&=d(f^*\eta\wedge f^*\omega)\\
&=df^*\eta\wedge f^*\omega-f^*\eta\wedge df^*\omega\\
&=f^*d\eta\wedge f^*\omega-f^*\eta\wedge f^*d\omega\\
&=f^*(d\eta\wedge\omega)-f^*(\eta\wedge d\omega)\\
&=f^*d(\eta\wedge\omega)
\end{align}$$